# Php Cannot Read Node Value in Xml

Tags: php, xml

I cannot able to read  node.I want to read the USER_ID node value.When i am trying to read with **simplexml_load_string**.

I am unable to read the node value.

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?> 
<RESULT>      
<SUCCESS>1</SUCCESS> 
<ERRMESSAGE /> 
<REMARKS /> 
<DATA>
  <data>
    <USERS>
      <U> 
        <USER_ID>1</USER_ID>
      </U>
  </data>
</DATA>
</RESULT>
```

Comment: So which node value are you trying to read, and how are you trying to read it?

Comment: The XML is invalid, the `U` element is not closed.

Comment: I am just trying to read by using $xml=simplexml_load_string($body);The result is showing like:          SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] =>  1                                                                                                                        )

Comment: U element is closed.But i am not able to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file is not valid. Change encoding of xml document to **utf-8**.
Then just access like normal object:

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$array = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr->DATA->data->USERS->U->USER_ID);
echo "</pre>";
```